# Highlight a specific cell based on the values of other cells

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

Example:

```
If ("E1") = 0 And ("F1") = 0 And ("G1") = 0 Then 
    ("A12").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ("A12").Font.ColorIndex = 0
```

Comment: Do you essentially need VBA to highlight cell when it can be done with Conditional Formatting --> `=AND(E1:G1=0)` ?

Comment: I have many configurations to apply and conditional  format doesn't offer sufficient options. That is why I believe VBA would work better.

Comment: I don't see a question. What do you actually need help with?

Comment: Do you mean `Range("E1")` etc?

Answer (score 1):

### Highlight If Equal to 0

- Zeros in Excel are often closely connected to empty or blank cells. When asking questions related to any of them, try to be as explicit as possible i.e. there is quite a number of ways your question could be interpreted i.e. this may not produce the desired result.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Changes the appearance of a cell if all cells of a range
'               contain only the number 0.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ColorCell()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("E1:G1")
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Cells.Count
    
    If Application.CountIf(srg, 0) = scCount Then
        With ws.Range("A12")
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            .Font.ColorIndex = 0
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

**Evaluate**

- Instead of the `If` statement in the code, you can use one of the following two:

```vb
' =COUNTIF(E1:G1,0)=3
If ws.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & srg.Address & ",0)=" & scCount) Then
If ws.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & srg.Address & ",0)=") = scCount Then
```

**Color**

- Instead of the `ColorIndex` you can use `Color` which is independent of any color scheme:

```vb
.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' 65536
.Font.Color = 0
```